# Data annotations working wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, data-annotations

I have a model which has a few required fields and some which does not have any validations. But my ModelState.IsValid is throwing me an error in spite of filling all those textboxes. I am using entity Framework. What am I missing?

Model

```
public class EDModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Number of beds")]
    public int Beds { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Number of Hospital Beds")]
    public int HospitalBeds { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<div class="divPanel">
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Id)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Beds )
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Beds, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", title = "Total number of beds available " })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Beds)

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HospitalBeds )
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HospitalBeds , new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", title = "Total number of hospital beds" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HospitalBeds )
        </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notes)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Notes, new { @class = "form-control", title = "" })

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Update(EDModel model)
    {
        if(model.Id==null || model.Id == default(Guid))
        {
            model.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }

        foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {
               var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage }); 
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried setting an ID inside the method thinking it might be the issue as it is a primary key in the DB but there is still the Model.IsValid error.

EDIT 1: I have added the modelstate errors but the error message says 'A value is required.' but not which field the issue is in.
EDIT 2: I added a validation for ID and that is where the issue is. The error is being thrown for no ID, inspite of me setting it in the controller. I added the code suggested and it still shows the id field as error.

I realize that model state error is on submit and there is no point setting it in the controller as there will still be an error. So how do I manage this case where the Id field might have value or may be null.

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: The model you have shown is named `EDModel` but the model in your view is `EDSaturationModel` - they are not the same

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have fixed it in the code.

Comment: Check the value of `ModelState` - what is the error (and as a side note, you do not need the `[Required]` attribute on `Beds` and `HospitalBeds` - they are typeof `int` and required by default - unless you want to add a specific error message)

Comment: Add the following in your controller to check the errors - `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please check my latest update.

Answer (score 1):

A `Guid` is a non-nullable type and thus is automatically `Required`. This could be causing your `ModelState` to be invalid if there is no value supplied in the `Model` of your page. You could solve this by making your `Guid` nullable by turning it into type `Guid?`, or by supplying a value for the `Id` field.

If this does not solve your issue, you could debug and check what is in `ModelState.Errors` to see what the cause of the error is.

Answer (score 1):

ModelState is an object that comes with errors since the form submit (from the view). Even when you are setting the Id (the guid), the ModelState remains as invalid.

I suggest you to remove your Hidden element for the Id and if you still need it to be initialized on the action method, keep the code as you have it.

```
        ...
        <div class="divPanel">
        @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)*@
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
        ...
```

Comment: There are situations when the id will be null and there are cases when there is an id from the Get method. How do I manage that?

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do in your action method (backend). Depending of your necessity set or not the id. But keep you ModelState valid or invalid depending of the fields you are allowing the user to set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the need to revalidate your model then you could one of the following methods from your controller class.

- `bool TryValidateModel(object model)`
- `void ValidateModel(object model)`

The difference between those two is that the `ValidateModel` will throw a `InvalidOperationException` if at least one validation fails.

If one of the above methods are not available to you or you are not on a controller class you can use the 
[Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) and the [ValidationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.aspx) classes.
Example:

```
var model = new SomeModel(); //Has DataAnnotation attributes
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model);
var list = new List<ValidationResult>();
 if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, list))
 {
    //Error on validation. Check the list for more details.
 }
```

For a better example and explanation about the `Validator` and `ValidationContext` can be found [here](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx)